# How to install latest MKVToolnix to Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, repository, mkv

MKVToolnix developer stopped providing repo for Ubuntu 16.04. Now mininum Ubuntu version he supports is 18.04

Can someone tell me how can I install latest version (40.0 right now) to a Ubuntu 16.04 without compiling it myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The good news is that there is now an AppImage for MKVToolNix which works well on Ubuntu 16.04. Only a couple of steps to download and install this:

1. Download the file [from here](https://www.fosshub.com/MKVToolNix.html?dwl=MKVToolNix_GUI-40.0.0-x86_64.AppImage) with your favourite browser, by default the AppImage will go to `$HOME/Downloads`
2. Navigate to this location and after right clicking on the downloaded AppImage select: Permissions --> 'Allow executing as a Program'
3. Double click on the downloaded file and start using MKVToolNix!

Below is a gratuitous screenshot of the latest MKVToolNix running on my Ubuntu 16.04 VM:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, works great!

Comment: @Josh Excellent news :)